# Data-init function executing twice

Tags: jquery-mobile, kendo-ui

I have a problem, I dont know why but my data-init function in a main view is being called when I navigate back to that page for the first time.  I want to separate some initialization logic from show logic in the starting view.

View is defined as a first (and only) view inside the body element.

```
<div data-role="view" id="..."  data-model="..." data-init="initFnc"  data-show="show">
</div>
```

I create the app like this:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { transition: "slide" });
```

So once again sequence of events, just to be clear:

1. app started, main view opened -> init and show functions called
2. navigate away to another view, navigate back -> init and show functions called
3. navigate away to another view, navigate back -> show function called

In step 2, I want to call only the "show" function.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is not normal - the init event should be fired once. Most likely your navigation goes wrong and loads your homepage as a remote view. Or you instantiate the app multiple times.

Comment: Thank you, I was navigating to the view as if it was remote view. # solved it. 
So init on first page executes not only when app starts, but also on first remote navigation to that view, didnt expect that.

Answer (score 1):

That does not seems to be the case, what you shared looks completely valid. Take a look in this [demo](http://jsbin.com/IVAluqI/2/edit).

Comment: Thanks, when I navigated, I navigated without #, as if it is remote view. So init on first page executes not only when app starts, but also on first remote navigation to that view.